# Full-upgrade to Debian testing fails due to libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, testing, dist-upgrade

I've just switched to bullseye (see sources below)

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main

deb http://security.debian.org testing-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org testing-security main contrib non-free
```

The update and upgrade went fine, but full-upgrade fails due to the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.3.0-6 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

From what I see on the packages.debian.org, Debian testing should have `libgcc-8-dev: 8.4.0-4`, so I don't see why an older version is to be installed.

How can I fix this, to finalize the bullseye full-upgrade?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602827/full-upgrade-to-debian-testing-fails-due-to-libc6-dev-breaks-libgcc-8-dev/603748#603748?newreg=64f9bae058c54437b82228b4a27633df

Comment: There's another (a new?) bug with the same symptoms but not solvable using the accepted answer: see https://superuser.com/a/1607419/100450

Comment: I reported the issue to Debian maintainers: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=981424 . I am leaving a comment here as I do not have enough reputation points to post an answer.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Installing `gcc-8-base` (`sudo apt install gcc-8-base`) appeared to do the trick for me and fix the problem for me.

Comment: sweet!  I've been going through trying to update the individual packages to no avail, this did the trick though thanks!

Comment: Right now this would even remove apt, so not a good idea. Sadly this isn't a planned transition (https://release.debian.org/transitions/).

Comment: I've tried installing gcc-8-base and then I got another error on mutter. So I've installed all three at once "sudo apt install gcc-8-base mutter libmpx2". For more information (https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?49704-Troubleshooting-Kali-apt-get-upgrade)

Comment: Installing this removes a bunch of packages like `dolphin evince g++ g++-8 gcc-8-base:i386 gdm3 gnome gnome-contacts gnome-core gnome-session gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-shell-pomodoro gnome-todo`
Why? Even my desktop `kde-plasma`

Comment: Definitely seems to have worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This answer tends to cause unwanted package removals, as @Amith mentions. There's a deeper issue with the buster -> bullseye upgrade path right now, apparently due to gcc renaming some packages and how apt resolves dependencies when a package `provide`s another. Info here: https://salsa.debian.org/rpavlik/gcc-10-compat (Apparently because this question is protected, my 100 reputation from having other SO/SE site accounts isn't enough to add a top-level answer...)

Comment: The answer is *not* the solution to this issue. According to the [Debian Buster release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrade-process) you should prepare for the operating system minimal system upgrade: `sudo apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs`

and then you can do a full upgrade:

`sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: The command `sudo apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs` is what caused this mess to begin with.

Answer (score 10):

If it still does not work try:
`apt-get install gcc-9-base`

Comment: worked for me. now im thinking whether gcc-10 would've also worked?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me after trying everything else:

> apt-get remove libgcc-8-dev

Answer (score -1):

@Laogeodritt mentioned this in one of the comments but I decided to post an answer because it is easier to find.
The only procedure that worked for me:

```
echo "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/rpavlik:/bullseye-fix/Debian_Testing/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bullseye-upgrade-fix.list
curl http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/rpavlik:/bullseye-fix/Debian_Testing/Release.key | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/bullseye-upgrade-fix.asc
sudo apt update
```

This adds repositories with transitional packages available named libgcc1,
etc. that depend on their renamed equivalents in bullseye.
After this you can run `dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade`.

Don't forget to remove the repositories after you reboot:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bullseye-upgrade-fix.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/bullseye-upgrade-fix.asc`
```

Source:
[1]: https://salsa.debian.org/rpavlik/gcc-10-compat

Comment: This didn't work for me, going from raspbian buster to raspberry pi OS bullseye.

Comment: I conceive of a situation where installing random packages from OpenSUSE on top of a Debian install would improve things.  If it happens to allow you to get passed the immediate dependency problem, it will cause far more in the future, and likely make the installation beyond repair.  Don't do it.