# Full-upgrade to Debian Testing fails due to libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.3.0-6 is to be installed

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, testing

I switched the sources to Bullseye and the upgrade went smoothly, but when I do a full-upgrade, I get:

```
libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.3.0-6 is to be installed
```

My sources are as follows:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main

#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

#deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
```

How can I fix this to finalize the upgrade?

P.S. I've looked at a recent issue here: [Full-upgrade to Debian testing fails due to libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592657/full-upgrade-to-debian-testing-fails-due-to-libc6-dev-breaks-libgcc-8-dev)

Which didn't help.

Comment: Note: There's another (a new?) bug with the same symptoms but not solvable using the accepted answer: see https://superuser.com/a/1607419/100450

Comment: I found the solution here: https://salsa.debian.org/rpavlik/gcc-10-compat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debian 10 uses GCC 8, but Debian 11 currently uses GCC 9 (probably 10 by the time it’s released). For some reason, in your case, the upgrade fails to replace the GCC 8 packages, and the upgrade is blocked.

To fix this, remove `gcc-8` and its dependencies.

This is a symptom of a more general problem with GCC libraries when upgrading from Debian 10 to testing; see [Ryan Pavlik’s repository](https://salsa.debian.org/rpavlik/gcc-10-compat) for a general solution and details of the problem, as well as links to bugs filed against GCC in the hope of an official fix.

Comment: That would remove 500+ packages. :(
LANG=C sudo apt-get install gcc-8-base- libgcc-8-dev- polkit-kde-agent-1 kde-l10n-de libreoffice  libqtcore4
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5core5a : Breaks: libqtcore4 (< 4:4.8.7+dfsg-20~) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-18 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @MKesper that indicates you have a bigger problem related to `libqtcore4` and `libqt5core5a`, not `gcc-8`. Please ask a new question with the full details.

Comment: I wonder if this is a general problem @StephenKitt, I'm seeing very similar symptoms as the OP here. Also on `buster` currently and it's more or less impossible to dist-upgrade to `bullseye` without removing a lot of stuff. :/

Comment: @PerLundberg yes, there is, see https://salsa.debian.org/rpavlik/gcc-10-compat for details...

Comment: Thanks for that link @StephenKitt, I discovered that repo as well some days ago and used it successfully to upgrade one of my machines to `bullseye`. Great to get it linked from here.

Answer (score -4):

see previous, this updated link:
[Full-upgrade to Debian testing fails due to libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592657/full-upgrade-to-debian-testing-fails-due-to-libc6-dev-breaks-libgcc-8-dev/604491#604491)

and this is what i did...

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get -f upgrade
# or
apt full-upgrade -y
```

nothing works right?

this worked for me:

```
apt-get install aptitude
apt-get install libgcc-8-dev
apt-get update
apt-get install synaptic
```

but the worst happened after that.

went to home folder and every other folder and its all gone:

```
Unable to create io-slave. 
Error loading '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/file.so'."
```

I am not shutting down my pc because of this because i know i will not be able to boot back up i just have a feeling.

link: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/unable-to-create-io-slave-klauncher-said-error-loading-usr-lib-qt-plugins-kf5-kio-file-so/25866

also look at anon35400795
Jun '17

> just restart (logout+login). That happens because Qt(Dolphin) loads this plugin, then you do an update and Qt conflicts the loadup of the new version, because its still holding the old version in RAM.

It worked for me!!!!

Comment: I’m not sure whether this is asking for help (because of all the folders which seem to have disappeared, although it’s not clear whether that’s just inside Dolphin) or explaining how to solve the problem in the question — if the latter, I’m dubious about advice which results in “every other folder and its all gone”...

Comment: Saying that you fear being able to reboot and that your home directories are gone makes me believe that this is not an answer to the question.  If you intended to claim that the 'restart (logout+login)' part solved the problem for you, perhaps that should be the extent of the answer, removing everything else.

Comment: I say that because the display manager is the top issue Of 2019-2020 with kali linux, i am fixing a lot of bugs so yes i fear some things because things break and I have to restore a clone hard drive to re engineer the fixes

Comment: Everything worked for me, the only problem i have later is the kde gdm3 lightdm just switching and can’t login gui style login page because of the switching around of the gui display manager or just entirely the display manager not loading on boot.